# Deep learning training the dataset which has gap

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm

I have a dataset of a sensor (station) for several years with this structure:

```
station Direction   year    month   day dayOfweek   hour    volume
  1009       3      2015      1      1      5        0        37
  1009       3      2015      1      1      5        1        20
  1009       3      2015      1      1      5        2        24
   ...       .       ..       ..     ..     ..       ..       ..
```

there is plenty of gap(missed value) in this data. For example there might be a month or several days missed. I fill the missed volumes with 0. I want to predict volume based on previous data. I used LSTM and the mean absolute percent error (MAPE) is quite high around 20 and I need to reduce it.

The main problem that I have is even for traning I have a gap. Is there any other techniqe in deep learning for these kind of data?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to handle missing values as listed here (https://machinelearningmastery.com/handle-missing-data-python/).

If i have enough data I will just ommit rows with missing data. If i do not have enough data and/or have to predict on cases where data is missing I normally try those two approaches and choose the one with the higher accuracy.

The same as you. I choose a distinct value which is not included in the dataset, like 0 in your case and fill in that value. The other approach is to use the mean or median of the training set. I use the same value (calculated on training set) in my validation set/test set. The median is better than the mean, if the mean does not make sense in the current context. (2014.5 as year for example).